# TCPDF UTF-8 symbols not showing up

Tags: php, pdf, utf-8, tcpdf

Im using latest TCPDF version(5.9). But have some strange problems with encoding. I need Lithuanian language symbols like: ąčęėįšųūž. But get only few of it. Other remain like ?????
So what should I do ? I use default times font(it comes with TCPDF download).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The encoding of generated PDF document is ANSI. Such information shows PDF reader. But how can it be ? I defined in my code, that encoding is UTF-8...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set the `$unicode` parameter on the TCPDF constructor to `false` and the `$encoding` parameter to `'ISO-8859-1'` or some other character map.

[This](http://www.krishnasunuwar.com.np/2011/05/tcpdf-html-to-pdf-conversion-encoding-problem-for-extended-chars/) will help you:

Default for UTF-8 unicode:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Example of constructor for European charset:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'ISO-8859-1', false);
```

Comment: Please mention the file that this line should be added/modifeid

Comment: this does absolutely not work, when the encoding of the text is acutally utf-8. in my case everything is more worse with setting parameters to >>false, 'ISO-8859-1'<<...

Comment: @emfi Dont forget to change the encoding of the source file itself from 'UTF-8' to 'ANSI'

Answer (score 33):

TCPDF is quite tricky with utf8. Best way to achieve what you want is to embed the font in generated PDF file itself. You can use freeserif font from the TCPDF package, it contains all the utf8 symbols, shows absolutely any character of any language, but adds ~700kb to the output file. That's probably the easiest way to get symbols you need if file size doesn't matter.

You could also make your own font to embed, containing the characters you need. That's probably the best solution, keeping it universal and small in size, but is more complex.

Alternatively, you can relay on core fonts, which are taken from the system, and if not found, replaced by a substitute. This makes output file extremely light, but adds the necessity of font subsetting to obtain exotic chars. Personally I haven't had a success with this, so I still think embedding font is the best solution, which also happens to be more universal..

Comment: Awesome tip with freesans font, I´d upvote you 10 times, saved me a lot of work!

Comment: Freesans also helped me. Thanks a lot! Also, I want to add that the 'freesans' font should be set both in PHP ($pdf->SetFont('freesans')) and in HTML, if you try to print tables, like I did. Just add the 'style' attribute like this: <td style="font-family: freesans;">...</td> Helped me to display some Czech characters.

Comment: "Best way to achieve what you want is to embed the font in generated PDF file itself." - how can i achieve that?

Comment: @squirrely i love you, parrker9 i love you

Comment: In my case, simply changing the font (to freesans) in the inline style of the original HTML (I am using writeHTML) did the trick. You need to have the font in the fonts folder, though.

Answer (score 16):

there is a font included in the CPDF core fonts - dejavusans, it shows all the lithuanian characters. Just add the following:

```
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array('dejavusans', '', 10, '', false));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array('dejavusans', '', 8, '', false));
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10, '', false);
```

Answer (score 14):

Set font to freeserif it will work.
I tested.

```
$pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 14, '', true);
```

Comment: can't believe took almost two hours to figure out

Comment: Thank you I was trying to write Greek in the header/footer and only this answer helped me. I had to pass the characters through `htmlentities()`, and now the freeserif font displays them correctly.

Answer (score 10):

Just discovered this same situation when trying to render Romanian text using the default Helvetica font. In doing some investigation I found that the tcpdf library treats it's default fonts (referred to as "core" fonts) as Latin1 characters so even if you tell it to use UTF-8 encoding and set the unicode flag, it will literally translate your text to Latin1 equivalents prior to rendering. The default behavior of the library is, if it finds a Latin1 equivalent, to translate each character that it can find an equivalent for otherwise it translates the character as '?'.

This can be found inside the TCPDF class in the following method chain:
`Write()` -> `Cell()` -> `getCellCode()` -> `_escapetext()`.

Inside of `_escapetext()` you can see it is checking for `$this->isunicode` then checking the selected font to see if it's type is **core|TrueType|Type1**. If it is, it will take the string an "latinize" it for you by way of the `UTF8ToLatin1()` method. This is where the '?' translations are taking place.

My recommendation would be to use a custom unicode font (like Deja Vu Sans) that is similar to the default font you are after. That worked for me in my current situation.

Comment: This was indeed my problem as well.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 8):

**To use TCPDF with special characters like ฿, 포 or others**
you need to use a ***unicode*** font:

1. **download** the font here:
   ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/unix/X11/multimedia/MPlayer/contrib/fonts/arialuni.ttf.bz2
2. create a test pdf file and load this font into TCPDF
   example:

   `$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('/var/www/app/images/fonts/arialuni.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);`
3. this will create the fonts like:

   > application/libraries/tcpdf/fonts/arialuni.ctg.z
   >   application/libraries/tcpdf/fonts/arialuni.php
   >   application/libraries/tcpdf/fonts/arialuni.z
4. now you can set the new font with :
   $pdf->SetFont('arialuni', '', 10.5);
5. and now you can use special unicode characters like ฿ and more....

Source : 
http://myridia.com/dev_posts/view/852

Comment: i am using version 6.2.12 and the method $pdf->addTTFfont() does not exist here? do you or someone else have any information?

Comment: @emfi, now "addTTFfont" is a static method. You can find the example here: https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/7214fa2103abc25d244f76991358a386c614a170/tools/tcpdf_addfont.php#L250

Answer (score 5):

You u have problem to read character like **Karnātaka** from database and display like this        **karn?taka**  I mean **"?"** which we don't want then do following things :

1. Define charset for the connection (`mysql_set_charset()`):

   ```
   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

   if (!$con)
   {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   mysql_select_db("database_name", $con) or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);
   ```
2. Use  `$pdf->SetFont('DejaVuSerif', '', 10);` instead of `$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 12);`

   - For TCPDF Library of the PHP read character like **Rājasthān** instead of **R?jasth?n** from database

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, you can define an encoding when you create a new font, [as described here](http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php).  Otherwise, you have to use the encoding that was defined when the font was created.  It sounds like the fonts that ship with TCPDF all use WinAnsiEncoding... a.k.a. code page 1252.

Clunky, but effective.

Comment: I can confirm this is how I got it working for Romanian characters. I tried generating Arial (ttf) in several ways but ultimately failed. It worked the first time when I tried with MyriadPro (utf).

Answer (score 3):

With default TCPDF package tested **dejavusans** and **freeserif** and both fonts works with lithuanian characters. I also typed few russian characters and they worked too. I used this code to test it:

```
$this->pdf = new \TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false); 
$this->pdf->AddPage();
$this->pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', 'B', 20); // UTF8 fonts with lithuanian support: freeserif, dejavusans
$this->pdf->Write(0, 'ąžūčšęėųįĄŽŪČŠĘĖŲĮ Превед Кросавчег!', '', 0, 'C', true, 0, false, false, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

With dejavusans font it worked fine for both Russian and Latvian letters.

Answer (score 1):

With me it was a font problem. I used the font `times`and my local multibyte chras wouldn't show up properly. When I changed it to `freeserif` they were working normally :)

Answer (score 0):

For this use the following code of the parameter TCPDF constructor

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'ISO-8859-1', false);
```

It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('C:\xampp\htdocs\copyshop\fonts\07-TH-Sarabun-PSK\THSarabun.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
    $pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 16,'',FALSE); //Working
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Romanian characters and the problem wasn't the encoding, *LC_CTYPE* or other setting from *TCPDF*, but the font I used.
I mention that I used TWIG templating with Courier font.
You can try to change your font to **freeserif**

Answer (score 0):

change the font to show normally ₹ and Lithuanian symbols

```
$pdf->SetFont('cid0cs', '', 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

To faced this issue and I had to use `dejavusans` font which is a UTF-8 Unicode font. This help fix the encoding issue when render UTF-8 words like `ąčęėįšųūž`.

However, I was using `helvetica` font which is standard ASCII font, and changing document's font to `dejavusans` make it ugly.

To fix this I set two fonts to be loaded in the document and specified a part of the document to use `dejavusans` font

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

/*
 ......
 set margins and other options
 ......
 */

// Set font
// dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, 
// if you only need to print standard ASCII chars, 
// you can use core fonts like helvetica or times to reduce file size.
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 12, '', true);
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12, '', true);

$html = '<div style="font-family: helvetica;">' . $clientName . '</div><div style="font-family: dejavusans;">' . $clientAddress . '</div>';

// Print text using writeHTMLCell()
$pdf->writeHTMLCell($w=0, $h=0, $x='', $y='', $html, $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);

$pdf->Output('invoice.pdf', 'I');
```