# TCPDF - Special characters(like this: • ) showing up as diamond question mark

Tags: php, pdf, utf-8, fonts, tcpdf

I know that TCPDF supports special characters and multiple languages.  I have tried all the provided fonts. I want to generate the PDF in UTF-8. I know that the included font 'freeserif' for sure includes the character in question.  "•"

Here is my current constructor call:

`$pdf=new MYPDF('P', 'mm', 'Letter', true, 'UTF-8', false);`

Here is an example of the character being generated:

`$this->Cell(80,6.35,"• $POST[reportTitle]",0,0,'L',true);`

I have also tried replacing the character with its html code:

`&#8226;`

Comment: Is `$POST[reportTitle]` actually `$_POST[reportTitle]`? I don't know whether it is possible to inject stuff into a PDF (JavaScript?) but if you're taking user input, might be worth ensuring it is untainted before you put it in.

Comment: Nope, $POST is an array I built myself, which contains the $_POST array a page back. It is not posting to the PDF, I pass it in the $_SESSION.  Sorry for the confusion, I didn't think to point that out!

Comment: Ah cool. Should be `$POST['reportTitle']` to avoid warnings, however.

Comment: I agree, however sometimes it confuses PHP when its in parameters. Not sure why.

Comment: Try wrapping it all in braces (I would anyway, tbh): `"• {$POST['reportTitle']}"` - the issue may be confusion between the outer speech marks and the inner apostrophes - make sure the inner set are apostrophes and not speech marks.

Answer (score 2):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333702/tcpdf-utf-8-problem) :

Set the `$unicode` parameter on the TCPDF constructor to `false` and the `$encoding` parameter to `'ISO-8859-1'` or some other character map.

[This](http://www.krishnasunuwar.com.np/2011/05/tcpdf-html-to-pdf-conversion-encoding-problem-for-extended-chars/) will help you:

Default for UTF-8 unicode:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Example of constructor for European charset:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'ISO-8859-1', false);
```

Comment: yeah I already tried that @adrien, but I tried it again just to triple-check it.  That makes all characters = The boxes, like this: [] but actually rectangles.  

Interestingly, if I paste the boxes here, we see that it is coming up as another language: 

牥灯

So it is just generating it incorrectly.

Comment: Are all your PHP code file encoded in UTF-8 ? (check with Notepad++ for example) + is your mysql connection in UTF-8 if you use one ? what about the encoding of your MySQL tables (if any) ? etc..

Comment: Good idea, tried it though and re-generated it. Refreshed all and posted new data, still the same results though. :( 

Checking the mysql connection shortly