# TCPDF - Not displaying UTF-8, latin characters

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

Im using TCPDF to generate pdf document with latin characters:

```
//TCPDF
require_once('class/tcpdf.php');
require_once('class/fpdi.php');

$pdf = new FPDI();
$template = "template.pdf";
$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($template);
$tplidx = $pdf->importPage(1);

$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($tplidx, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 14, '', false);
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(false);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetXY(10,18);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"šđžč",0,1, 'C');

$file_name = str_replace('.','_'.date('Y-m-d').'.',$template);
$pdf->Output($file_name, 'D');
```

Problem is that all non standard characters are converted to symbol "?"

Comment: Have you tested to generate all with UTF-8?

Comment: I think your issue is related to encoding. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333702/tcpdf-utf-8-problem

Answer (score 4):

Just add this line before `$pdf->AddPage()`

```
$pdf->setFont('freeserif');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the **solution to all the problems about writing special characters using TCPDF php script**.

Follow these steps and you will get it solved:

1. **Edit your PHP using ANSI codification**. You set it easily with Notepad++ editor.
2. When you need to write something with TCPDF methods, dont forget enclosing the texts inside `utf8_encode()` php function.

This way:

```
$pdf->Cell(210, 18, utf8_encode('Camión/pícaro/rúbrica/áéíóú...  Hello world, this is Aberasturi from the Moon'),0, $ln=0, 'C', 0, '', false, false, 'T', 'C');
```

Ondo ibili!!!!

X.Aberasturi

Comment: This is a better solution than using sans serif as a font.

Answer (score 0):

From the tcpdf source code:

- IMPORTANT: Please note that this method sets the mb_internal_encoding to ASCII, so if you are using the mbstring module functions with TCPDF you need to correctly set/unset the mb_internal_encoding when needed.

This just cost me an hour, maybe it helps someone else.