# tcpdf: flipped sentence when using special characters

Tags: php, tcpdf

We faced a strange problem when generating pdfs with tcpdf. Usually we grab strings from our (utf-8) database and put it in a smarty template. This is pushed into tcpdf to arrange the invoices, delivery notes and so on. It works as expected.
Now we tried to use specia characters. I just stored in our database the string:

≥ ≤ ™ ס қ К μ λ γ β α Ω × ® ± ² ³
This is a normal sentence.

The output in the pdf is:

.sentence normal a is This ³ ² ± ® × Ω α β γ λ μ К қ ס ™ ≥ ≤

(Linebreak missing and other myteries :))

Could someone tell me what is going wrong there?

Comment: This is really a strange problem... I am not sure if `answer` of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333702/tcpdf-utf-8-problem) suits to your requirement... but you can give it a try

Comment: ty for your reply. we already use dejavusans. we left arialuni behind due to the pdf-size...

Comment: I found out that the Omega sign (ס) caused the problem described above.
I would really appreciate if someone could clear this out...

Comment: Ok, that was too fast, it's not the Omega sign (like I was told), its the 15th letter of the hebreic alphabet (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A1)
So, tcpdf parses the string, if a hebreic sign is found it changes the direction???