# how to Output a file name in Hebrew in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

how to output file name in Hebrew in CodeIgniter?
I have a sys I have to build on CodeIgniter and one of the options is to export pdf from sys, i want the pdf to be in Hebrew letters e.g "שלום.pdf"
but for some reason it's not working for me, I get blank file name I have tried to change the encoding on the server to utf 8 and still no luck.

can anyone help our, encountered this issue, or has any directions i can look at?

help much appreciated!

Comment: what pdf library are you using? did you check support of Hebrew filenames of this library?

Comment: @Vickel using tcpdf

Comment: please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333702/tcpdf-utf-8-lithuanian-symbols-not-showing-up it may have the solution